# How do I change an object's property within an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a grocery list I have to make. I'm asked to add a purchase to the list, noting that if a product already exists, the amount needs to be increased in the existing purchase, not in a new one.

So far I've created the array of objects but I can't figure out how to update an object in the array.

```js
// The 'bought' property is the amount needed to be bought
const grocery = [
    {
        name: 'soda',
        amount: 0,
        bought: true
    }, {
        name: 'ketchup',
        amount: 2,
        bought: false
    }, {
        name: 'steak',
        amount: 4,
        bought: false
    }, {
        name: 'nutella',
        amount: 0,
        bought: true
    }, {
        name: 'cheese',
        amount: 1,
        bought: false
    }, {
        name: 'fruit',
        amount: 5,
        bought: false
    }
];

// This is what I've found online, but I can't figure out how to make it work for my code
addItem = function(bought, amount) {
    var foundItem = grocery.filter(function(bought) {
        return grocery.bought === bought;
    })[0];
  
    if (foundItem) {
        grocery.amount++;
    } else {
        return grocery.push({
            name: 'cheese',
            amount: -1,
            bought: true
      });
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, when adding an item to the list, which values you will pass to the addItem function?

Comment: `grocery.amount++;` should be `foundItem.amount++` Using Array#find() would be better approach than using Array#filter() also

Comment: I'm not sure about the function - I tried to make it work for my case but I wasn't sure how. The values I need to pass to the addItem function are the name, amount, and 'bought'. Ideally, if the product already exists in the array and the 'bought' property is false for that item, it would be changed to true.

Comment: So you need to `find()` by matching `name` to start with since that is the only unique property value you can use. As for `bought` that needs more details how it needs to work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the updated code for the function. Thanks to all the helpful comments!

```js
addItem = function(name,amount) {
    var foundItem = grocery.findIndex((grocery)=>grocery.name===name);
    if (foundItem !==-1) {
       grocery[foundItem].amount = grocery[foundItem].amount + amount;
       grocery[foundItem].bought = true;
     } else {
        return grocery.push({
            name: name,
            amount: amount,
            
        });
    }
};
addItem(prompt('What do you want to add to your list?'), parseInt(prompt('How many?')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use findIndex method to find existing product Name.

```
 addItem = function(name,amount) {
 var foundItem = grocery.findIndex((data)=>data.name===name && data.bought);
 if (foundItem !==-1) {
    grocery[foundItem].amount = grocery[foundItem].amount + amount;
  } else {
    return grocery.push({
        name: 'cheese',
        amount: -1,
        bought: true
  });
  }
 };


 addItem("soda",20);
```

Comment: I hope I am able to answer your question.

Comment: Okay so I updated the return statement to push the name given in the function as well as the amount, and it's working fine.

 However, when I add a product that is already on the list, it gets added as a new element in the array instead of updating the product's amount property. Any idea how I could fix that?

Comment: Yeah ,You can use the findIndex method just like I have shown above and if you find the index update the amount and if not then push the object .